# wine error when I try open games

Tags: wine, games

i would like play *Blade and soul* on my Ubuntu 14.04 but when i try start terminal shows me error:

> fixme:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_IsLoadable 0x7ea82204 0x33f5e8
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at EnglishPatch.My.MyProject.get_Application () [0x00000] in :0 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at EnglishPatch.My.MyProject.get_Application () [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it (mscoree.dll) part of MS .NET Framework?
If I am correct (NullReferenceException), you should install it by means of [winetricks](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17886)

Comment: In particular one needs `winetricks dontnet20` according to multiple people who run the game successfully.

Comment: When I try install .NET 4.0, instalator shows me _Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer._

Comment: @DavidFoersterWhen I try install dotnet20 instalator shows me error _Cannot install on 64-bit operating system. This product is not supported on a 64-bit operating system.Setup will now exit_